# c++ c-style zero-initialization { 0 }

Tags: c++, c, arrays

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization shows that zero-initialization happens in the following scenario:

```
int array[32] = {};
```

; but never says anything about this:

```
int array[32] = { 0 };
```

Does the latter also zero-initialize the whole array in c++, or only the first element? If so, is it also true for structs?

Comment: The latter is particularly peculiar to use because any other value initializes only the first element (and zeroes the rest, thx to @ChrisDodd for clarifying that)...

Comment: For what it's worth `int array[4] = { 1 };` would produce `{1, 0, 0, 0}` so don't think the latter syntax initializes the whole array with that value.

Comment: @Resurrection: not true -- any array initializer that is smaller than the array will zero initialize all the trailing (unspecified) elements.

Comment: a C statement like:  `int array[32] = {};` results in the compiler outputting the following: "untitled2.c:1:17: warning: ISO C forbids empty initializer braces [-Wpedantic]"  suggest:   `int array[32] = {0};`  Notice the initializer inside the braces.  However, if you want to use a value other than 0, suggest: `for( size_t i = 0; i< 32; i++ ) { array[i] = 1; }`

Comment: the C language and the C++ language are very different, (and getting further apart with each new release)  Please pick one and erase the other tag

Comment: @user3629249 C... Hmm... C... C++. I wonder if they are related. >pastes C project code from stack overflow into c++ project >compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the latter also zero-initialize the whole array in c++, or only the first element?

Yes.

The first style is C++ style.

The second one is old C style.

Both zero initialise the whole array elements (not just the first element).

> If so, is it also true for structs?

Yes.

Comment: *Both zero initialise the whole array elements* this can be misleading. It's true only if the value used in the initializer is `0`. Otherwise, any array initializer shorter than the size of the array will initialize trailing values with `0`.

Comment: Yes that's what the question is about `{0}`. What you said is correct (if the value used in the initialised is something else), thanks

Comment: _"The second one is old C style"_ -- is there a new C style for this?

Answer (score 6):

ISO/IEC N489 [§9.4.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf#subsection.9.4.1) states

> - <sup>(5)</sup> For a non-union aggregate, each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows:
>
>   - <sup>(5.1)</sup> If the element has a default member initializer (11.4), the element is initialized from that initializer.
>   - <sup>(5.2)</sup> Otherwise, if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list (9.4.4).
>   - <sup>(5.3)</sup> Otherwise, the program is ill-formed.

[§9.4.4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf#subsection.9.4.4) states

> - <sup>(3.11)</sup> Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

*Value-initialization* of a scalar leads to its *zero-initialization*. Thus, the second one explicitly initializes with 0 only `array[0]` and the rest of the elements will be zero-initialized.

---

Thus, the following code

```
int array[4] = {13};
```

initializes `array` with values

```
{13, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ...but never says anything about this

It does. This is actually [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization).

As per cppreference:

> **If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members and bases or initializer list is completely empty**, the remaining members and bases  are initialized by their default member initializers, if provided in the class definition, **and otherwise by empty lists**, in accordance with the usual list-initialization rules (which performs value-initialization for non-class types and non-aggregate classes with default constructors, and aggregate initialization for aggregates). If a member of a reference type is one of these remaining members, the program is ill-formed.

This guaruntees that the remaining elements of the array are initialized with empty lists. For `int` (which is scalar) this initializes it to zero. For structs this would perform value-initialize if the struct is not an aggregate or aggregate-initialize otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CppInsights](https://cppinsights.io/s/a7f52090) to see what actually happens:

This:

```
int main()
{
    int array0[5];
    int array1[5] = {};
    int array2[5] = { 0 };
    int array3[5] = { -1 };
    int array4[5] = { 1, 2 };
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
int main()
{
  int array0[5];
  int array1[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array2[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array3[5] = {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int array4[5] = {1, 2, 0, 0, 0};
}
```

So, `int array2[5] = { v }` explicitly initializes the first element with `v`, and default initializes all other elements.